# Intersect between some DbGeography elements doesn´t work with Entity Framework 5

Tags: .net, sql, intersect

What is wrong with that??

```
const string lonMin="-19";      
const string latMin = "25";
const string lonMax = "-24";
const string latMax = "25.6";

//Create a polygon
var geoEncuadre = DbGeography.FromText("POLYGON ((" + lonMin + " " + latMin + "," +
            lonMax + " " + latMin + ","+ lonMax + " "+ latMax +","+lonMin+" " + latMax +","+lonMin + " "+latMin +  "))", 4326);
//Check for every node if intersects with the polygon
var nodos = (from n in _bd.Nodo
             where n.Geo.Intersects(geoEncuadre)
             select n).ToList();
```

This throws an `EntityCommandExecutionException`. It´s weird because if I use *DbGeometry* instead *DbGeography* it works fine. 
What happen with the *DbGeography* and the *Intersect* operation?

Comment: Ok, I got it. As use to happen is the most silly thing, the lonMax and lonMin are mistaken. Anyway I post an interesting link about some usual problems with the order in the creation of the Geography Polygons [here](http://blog.tallan.com/2012/04/10/new-spatial-features-in-sql-server-2012/)